# getting "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val' " while compareing binary tree in python

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I am trying to compare two binary tree p and q but  continuosly an error is raised saying "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'". I am not able to get over the error.
Can you please help me in resolving the issue and improve my understanding please?
Please find the code below:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.

p = [1,2,3]
q = [1,2,3]
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, v=0, l=None, r=None):
            self.val = v
            self.left = l
            self.right = r

    def compareBinaryTree(self, p, q):
        stack = [(p, q)]
        while stack:
            node1, node2 = stack.pop()
            print(node1,node2)
            if not node1 and not node2:
                continue
            elif None in [node1, node2]:
                return False
            else:
                if node1.val != node2.val:
                    return False
                stack.append((node1.right, node2.right))
                stack.append((node1.left, node2.left))
        return True
```

Please find below the error which is displayed while running the code:

```
>>>TreeNode.compareBinaryTree(t,p,q)

[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-1372e5b88a65> in <module>
----> 1 TreeNode.compareBinaryTree(t,p,q)

<ipython-input-23-5eef65d6c59b> in compareBinaryTree(self, p, q)
     18                 return False
     19             else:
---> 20                 if node1.val != node2.val:
     21                     return False
     22                 stack.append((node1.right, node2.right))

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'**
```

Comment: Could you please update your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the time of writing, we have no idea how you're initialized this class. as the error indicates, `list` doesn't have an attribute `val`, your class `TreeNode` however seems to have it. Can we assume that the list you've given examples of are initialized versions of `TreeNode`? If so, please share that initialization.

Answer (score 0):

`p` and `q` seem to be lists and not trees. `[1, 2, 3]` is a list and I think you mean to pass another instance of `TreeNode` instead.